# How to emulate EBO when using raw storage?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a component I use when implementing low-level generic types that store an object of arbitrary type (may or may not be a class type) which may be empty to take advantage of the [empty base optimization](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization):

```
template <typename T, unsigned Tag = 0, typename = void>
class ebo_storage {
  T item;
public:
  constexpr ebo_storage() = default;

  template <
    typename U,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
      !std::is_same<ebo_storage, std::decay_t<U>>::value
    >
  > constexpr ebo_storage(U&& u)
    noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<T,U>::value) :
    item(std::forward<U>(u)) {}

  T& get() & noexcept { return item; }
  constexpr const T& get() const& noexcept { return item; }
  T&& get() && noexcept { return std::move(item); }
};

template <typename T, unsigned Tag>
class ebo_storage<
  T, Tag, std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>::value>
> : private T {
public:
  using T::T;

  constexpr ebo_storage() = default;
  constexpr ebo_storage(const T& t) : T(t) {}
  constexpr ebo_storage(T&& t) : T(std::move(t)) {}

  T& get() & noexcept { return *this; }
  constexpr const T& get() const& noexcept { return *this; }
  T&& get() && noexcept { return std::move(*this); }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
class compressed_pair : ebo_storage<T, 0>,
                        ebo_storage<U, 1> {
  using first_t = ebo_storage<T, 0>;
  using second_t = ebo_storage<U, 1>;
public:
  T& first() { return first_t::get(); }
  U& second() { return second_t::get(); }
  // ...
};

template <typename, typename...> class tuple_;
template <std::size_t...Is, typename...Ts>
class tuple_<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...> :
  ebo_storage<Ts, Is>... {
  // ...
};

template <typename...Ts>
using tuple = tuple_<std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>, Ts...>;
```

Lately I've been messing about with lock-free data structures and I need nodes that optionally contain a live datum. Once allocated, nodes live for the lifetime of the data structure but the contained datum is only alive while the node is active and not while the node sits in a free list. I implemented the nodes using raw storage and placement `new`:

```
template <typename T>
class raw_container {
  alignas(T) unsigned char space_[sizeof(T)];
public:
  T& data() noexcept {
    return reinterpret_cast<T&>(space_);
  }
  template <typename...Args>
  void construct(Args&&...args) {
    ::new(space_) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  void destruct() {
    data().~T();
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct list_node : public raw_container<T> {
  std::atomic<list_node*> next_;
};
```

which is all fine and dandy, but wastes a pointer-sized chunk of memory per node when `T` is empty: one byte for `raw_storage<T>::space_`, and `sizeof(std::atomic<list_node*>) - 1` bytes of padding for alignment. It would be nice to take advantage of EBO and allocate the unused single-byte representation of `raw_container<T>` atop `list_node::next_`.

My best attempt at creating a `raw_ebo_storage` performs "manual" EBO:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct alignas(T) raw_ebo_storage_base {
  unsigned char space_[sizeof(T)];
};

template <typename T>
struct alignas(T) raw_ebo_storage_base<
  T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_empty<T>::value>
> {};

template <typename T>
class raw_ebo_storage : private raw_ebo_storage_base<T> {
public:
  static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<raw_ebo_storage_base<T>>::value, "");
  static_assert(alignof(raw_ebo_storage_base<T>) % alignof(T) == 0, "");

  T& data() noexcept {
    return *static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(
      static_cast<raw_ebo_storage_base<T>*>(this)
    ));
  }
};
```

which has the desired effects:

```
template <typename T>
struct alignas(T) empty {};
static_assert(std::is_empty<raw_ebo_storage<empty<char>>>::value, "Good!");
static_assert(std::is_empty<raw_ebo_storage<empty<double>>>::value, "Good!");
template <typename T>
struct foo : raw_ebo_storage<empty<T>> { T c; };
static_assert(sizeof(foo<char>) == 1, "Good!");
static_assert(sizeof(foo<double>) == sizeof(double), "Good!");
```

but also some undesirable effects, I assume due to violation of strict aliasing (3.10/10) although the meaning of "access the stored value of an object" is debatable for an empty type:

```
struct bar : raw_ebo_storage<empty<char>> { empty<char> e; };
static_assert(sizeof(bar) == 2, "NOT good: bar::e and bar::raw_ebo_storage::data() "
                                "are distinct objects of the same type with the "
                                "same address.");
```

This solution also potential for undefined behavior upon construction. At some point the program must construct the containee object within the raw storage with placement `new`:

```
struct A : raw_ebo_storage<empty<char>> { int i; };
static_assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(int), "");
A a;
a.value = 42;
::new(&a.get()) empty<char>{};
static_assert(sizeof(empty<char>) > 0, "");
```

Recall that despite being empty, a complete object necessarily has non-zero size. In other words, an empty complete object has a value representation that consists of one or more padding bytes. `new` constructs complete objects, so a conforming implementation could set those padding bytes to arbitrary values at construction instead of leaving memory untouched as would be the case for constructing an empty base subobject. This would of course be catastrophic if those padding bytes overlay other live objects.

So the question is, is it possible to create a standard-compliant container class that uses raw storage/delayed initialization for the contained object *and* takes advantage of EBO to avoid wasting memory space for the representation of the contained object?

Comment: @Columbo If the container type is derived from the contained type,  constructing/destroying a container object necessarily constructs/destroys the contained subobject. For construction, that means you either lose the ability to pre-allocate container objects or must delay their construction until you're ready to construct a containee. Not a big deal, it just adds another thing to track - allocated-but-not-yet-constructed container objects. *Destroying* a container object with a dead containee subobject is a harder problem, however - how do you avoid the base class destructor?

Comment: Ah, excuse me there. Forgot that delayed construction/destruction isn't possible this way and the implicit destructor call.

Comment: `    template <typename T>
    struct alignas(T) raw_ebo_storage_base<
      T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_empty<T>::value>
    >:T {};
`?  With maybe more tests on `T` to ensure it is vacuously constructed...  or some way to ensure that you can construct `T` without constructing `T`, assuming `T::T()` has side effects.  Maybe a traits class for non-vacuously constructed/destroyed `T` that says how to vacuously construct a `T`?

Comment: Another thought: have the ebo storage class take a list of types you aren't allowed to treat as empty, because the address of the ebo storage class will overlap with it if it does?

Comment: For the T is empty case, why not just call its ctor and dtor against int sized raw storage on the stack?

Comment: Why do you want to store empty objects? If you have two empty objects, how do they differ? So simply use void pointers and cast if you really need a type since there is no access to any member.

Comment: On bringup you'll atomically pull an item from a free list, construct it, and atomically put it into a tracking list.  On teardown you will be atomically removing from a tracking list, calling a destructor, and then atomically inserting into the free list.  So at the constructor and destructor calls the atomic pointer isn't in use and could be freely modified, correct?  If so the question will be: can you put the atomic pointer into the `space_` array and safely use it while it's unconstructed on the free list?  Then `space_` won't contain T but some wrapper around T and the atomic pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you gave the answer yourself in your various observations:

1. You want raw memory and placement new. This requires to have *at least one byte* available, even if you want to construct an empty object via placement new.
2. You want *zero bytes* overhead for storing any empty objects.

These requirements are self-contradicting. The answer therefore is **No**, that is not possible.

You could change your requirements a bit more, though, by requiring the zero byte overhead only for empty, trivial types.

You could define a new class trait, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
struct constructor_and_destructor_are_empty : std::false_type
{
};
```

Then you specialize

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
class raw_container;

template <typename T>
class raw_container<
    T,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_empty<T>::value and
        std::is_trivial<T>::value>>
{
public:
  T& data() noexcept
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<T&>(*this);
  }
  void construct()
  {
    // do nothing
  }
  void destruct()
  {
    // do nothing
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct list_node : public raw_container<T>
{
  std::atomic<list_node*> next_;
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
using node = list_node<empty<char>>;
static_assert(sizeof(node) == sizeof(std::atomic<node*>), "Good");
```

Of course, you still have

```
struct bar : raw_container<empty<char>> { empty<char> e; };
static_assert(sizeof(bar) == 1, "Yes, two objects sharing an address");
```

But that is normal for EBO:

```
struct ebo1 : empty<char>, empty<usigned char> {};
static_assert(sizeof(ebo1) == 1, "Two object in one place");
struct ebo2 : empty<char> { char c; };
static_assert(sizeof(ebo2) == 1, "Two object in one place");
```

But as long as you always use `construct` and `destruct` and no placement new on `&data()`, you're golden.

Comment: Thanks to @Deduplicator for making me aware of the power of `std::is_trivial` :-)